# How to define gateway for 192.168.1.1 as 10.0.0.x with `route add`?

Tags: command-line, routing

Let's say `eth0` has an ip `10.0.0.10` and its gateway is `10.0.0.1`. I want to add a route for `192.168.1.1` to use this interface.

What is the difference between these 3 commands?

```
route add -host 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
route add -host 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.10
route add -host 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.10 dev eth0
```

And which is preferred to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want

> `route add -host 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0`

Traffic going to `192.168.1.1` will go through `eth0` (rather then `wlan` or any other interface)

> `route add -host 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.10`

Tells all traffic going to `192.168.1.1` on all network interfaces to go through `10.0.0.10` as the gateway.

> `route add -host 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.10 dev eth0`

Same thing, but only applies to traffic on `eth0` (and not say `eth1` or `wlan`)

Which one you would want is dependent on your hardware and network configuration. If all you have is `eth0` it may not matter.

Comment: Note that the second one, for "All Network Interfaces" would include 'lo' (local loopback) under that - that would still be specially handled and isolated from that 'default route'.  The system sees 'lo' as a network interface, hence the comment.